# Sandbox API credentials are not working

Tags: testing, paypal, shopping-cart

I have setup set zen cart payment express checkout module to sandbox mode so that i can test it but sandbox API credentials are not working and Website do not direct to sandbox.payal .Any one can tell me why this happen?
Thank You..

Comment: Can any one take some seconds to help me plz.

Comment: Can you tell us what is happening? Are you getting errors? Any information would be helpful.